# How do I get a list of static methods inside a javascript class

Tags: javascript, static, ecmascript-6

I would like to get a list of methods from a class that are static.

```
class Person {
    constructor(){
        let x = this.getStaticMethods(); // how?? - would return [Person.Emails]
    }
    static Emails(){
        // returns emails
    }
}
```

I need the function itself (bound or unbound) not just the name. How would I get these?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
class Person {
    constructor(){
       let staticMethods = Object.create(null);
       for(var attr in Person) {
         if(typeof Person[attr] === 'function') {
           staticMethods[attr] = Person[attr];
         }
       }
        console.log(staticMethods);
    }
    static Emails(){
        // returns emails
    }
}

const p = new Person();
```

You should probably add `hasOwnProperty` to the final version, but this will get you most of the way there. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjeMEd

Comment: Actually, it won't. Methods are non-enumerable.

Comment: @Bergi it works with Babel, but I understand that the spec defines them as non-enumerable

Comment: Not with Babel in high-compliance mode either :-)